# iPad navigation for South Africa

Tags: ipad

Is there an iPad app that will give me turn-by-turn instructions for south africa, or do I need to use an iPhone app and the 2X button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NAVIGON MobileNavigator for South Africa](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/navigon-mobilenavigator-southern/id328325321?mt=8) is what you're looking for.
It's a universal app running both on the iPad and the iPhone/iPod touch.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any iPad specific apps for South African turn-by-turn navigation.

But, [ALK Technologies, Ltd](http://itunes.apple.com/nz/artist/alk-technologies-ltd/id324327454) has iPad software for North America and Europe, and iPhone apps for South Africa - so I think your best bet would be to write to them or [facebook them](http://www.facebook.com/copilotlive) and ask when the South African version is coming out. If you're on safari and fleeing from lions and elephants I don't know if the iPhone version will be big enough to see clearly!

NB: Apple.StackExchange.Com takes no responsibility for Lion or Elephant related accidents.

Comment: Thank you, I think i will end up using the iPhone version on the iPad with the 2X mode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

[HERE WeGo](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id955837609) supports turn-by-turn navigation. The app is iPhone only and you will have to run it on an iPad and use 2x scaling. This USP of the app is that it supports offline downloading of maps on per country basis.

You won't need active Internet connection on your iPad while navigating, but the app uses GPS to locate you, hence it will work only on **Wi-Fi + Cellular** variant of iPad as it contains the necessary GPS hardware.